# Trying to iterate through rows in a pandas dataframe and remove rows that don't contain a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to iterate through rows in a pandas dataframe and remove any rows that don't contain a dict. Here's the code I'm currently using.

```
for ind in df.index:
    test=False
    for i in df.iloc[ind]:
        if type(i)==dict:
            test=True
    if test==False:
        df.drop([ind],inplace=True)
```

However, not all of the rows without dicts are being deleted, and I get the following error: `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`. If I run the code again some more rows are deleted, but again, not all.

I'm trying to figure out why all of the rows without dicts are not being removed on the first pass. If anyone could please let me know I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you `drop` a row, your dataframe is actually reducing in length. However, your loop is still running on the old `df.index`, thus going out of range.

For example, say you have a `df` with 5 rows, and are currently at `ind = 3`, and this row does not have a dict. You drop it, and try to access the next row at `ind = 4`. However, your dataframe has dropped row 3 previously and reduced in length by 1 - thus throwing an error.

You can test this out yourself like this:

```
for ind in df.index:
    test=False
    try:
        for i in df.iloc[ind]:
            if type(i)==dict:
                test=True
        if test==False:
            df.drop([ind],inplace=True)
    except:
        print('Failed!', end=' ')
    print(f'At index {ind}, length of df: {len(df)}')

# Out:
At index 0, length of df: 5
At index 1, length of df: 4
At index 2, length of df: 3
Failed! At index 3, length of df: 3
Failed! At index 4, length of df: 3
```

Comment: I had a feeling something like this was going on but I'm still not sure how to avoid it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I didn't post any solution since you only asked why the error was happening : )  A simple solution, for example, can be if you store the faulty indices in a list if test==False, and drop them all together after the loop ends.

Comment: You're right, I should've been more clear. Thanks for the quick reply!